# Using react-quill for a blog app so users can create posts. How do I properly display a string of html elements in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, quill

I'm creating a blog app in React and Rails and I started using react-quill for users to post articles. However, when a user submits their post, the output is a string of HTML elements.

For Example: `<p>Line1</p><br /><p>Line2</p>`

How might I go about parsing the HTML string so it can display properly?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render HTML from a string.

**Example**

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: "<p>Line1</p><br /><p>Line2</p>" }}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML is the right way to choose. However, It will be dangerous because your website will be vulnerable for some issues like XSS. You should sanitize HTML to allow some tags and attributes only before pass to the  dangerouslySetInnerHTML. You can use this package for that.: https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html